# What is the expectation of the Dirac delta function of a random variable

Tags: probability, expectation, dirac-delta

I have a Dirac delta function as follows:

$\delta_{\epsilon = y}$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, and $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

I want to take the expectation of this function, but it appears that it would, by definition, be $\infty * P(\epsilon = y)$, which isn't well defined.

Is that accurate, or am I missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the result is simply the density of $\epsilon$ at y.

Comment: Well $\int_\Bbb R \delta_{\epsilon=y}\, g(\epsilon)\,\mathrm d \epsilon = g(y)$ from the definition of the Dirac delta generalised function.  So when $g$ is the density function of a random variable, that result is obtained from definition of expectation.  Whether it is meaningful is another matter.